# Return only date from SQL Server CE datetime using linq-to-entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

Is there a way to get a linq query to return just the date portion of a datetime. I've tried all the suggestions I can find, all of which generate errors at runtime. This is just the select portion of the query along with each error message (the rest of the query works great):

```
select new { d.id, d.date.Value.Date };
```

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

```
select new { d.id, date=EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.date) };
```

> The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact. [ Name of function = TRUNCATETIME,Data type (if known) =  ]

```
select new { d.id, date=d.date.Value.Month + "/" + d.date.Value.Day };
```

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

```
select new { d.id, date=d.date.Value.Month.ToString() + "/" + d.date.Value.Day.ToString() };
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
select new { d.id, date=String.Concat(d.date.Value.Month, "/")};
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Concat(System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select new {
    d.id,
    date = SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", d.date) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", d.date)
};
```

It will give you a string with `month/day` pattern.

But I would go with following:

```
(from r in row
...
select new { d.id, date = d.date.Value })
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new { x.id, x.date.Date });
```

It would select whole datetime from db and move date-only selection into LINQ to objects query.

Comment: SqlFunctions.DatePart(): This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities. The second one returns date & time, with all the times set to 12:00: x.date.Value.Date

Comment: This works!  Thanks a million MarcunJuraszek!!.Select(x => new { x.id, date = x.date.Value.ToShortDateString() });